# manually trigger omniauth callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, twitter-oauth

Is there any way I can trigger omniauth callback manually?

What I mean to say is, I get the oauth response from twitter in json, can I then POST/GET this data to the omniauth callback url ? If so, is there any specific format in which I should re-structure the json data?

I am doing something on these lines but unable to populate the `request.env['omniauth.auth']` in the omniauth callback.

Here is the request spec

```
before(:each) do
  # response returned from twitter is in spec/fixtures/oauth_twitter_response.json
  twitter_oauth_response = File.join(Rails.root.to_s, 'spec', 'fixtures', 'oauth_twitter_response.json')
  data = File.read(twitter_oauth_response)
  @twitter_data = JSON.parse(data)
end

it 'should post the twitter data to omniauth callback' do
  post 'users/auth/twitter/callback', {}, {:env => {"omniauth.auth" => @twitter_data}}
end
```

any idea if this is possible at all?

Comment: You could use this https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. The only thing you're missing is what you're having trouble with - setting `omniauth.auth`. You do it like this:

```
controller.stub!(:env).and_return('omniauth.auth' => @twitter_data)
```

Comment: where do I add this? Should I replace the `post 'users/.. '` with the one you provided? Sorry, I am new to rspec... I forgot to mention the above code goes in request spec. Also would it be possible for a client app to post the json data to the callback url? Say for example, can I post the json data through ajax to the callback url and the `request.env['omniauth.auth']` gets populated?

Comment: You want to put it in a `before :each` block in rspec. I'm not sure what you mean when you say 'client app'... this is just for testing.